# How do we know that user has enabled or disabled for notification service for our app in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, settings

I am using push notifications in my application using Firebase.

How do we know whether or not the user has enabled the notification service in his settings for our app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531103/swift-ios-check-if-remote-push-notifications-are-enabled-in-ios9-and-ios10 possible duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift ios check if remote push notifications are enabled in ios9 and ios10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531103/swift-ios-check-if-remote-push-notifications-are-enabled-in-ios9-and-ios10)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way you can alter `push notification` on the `client-side`,
unless you can make sure the app is running so you can filter out the `notification`.

But you can do some workaround on your backend. You can collect all the `client` `token` on your backend, and save whether the client is turning the push notification on or off. In this way, you can send the push notification only for the client who has enabled push notification.

Comment: Actually we are proving sms messages and notifications , I want to which users are enable the notifications I disable the sms service to him for overcoming of duplicity that purpose only.

Comment: How to I know user is enable or not for notifications for saving purpose only.

Comment: if you mean, knowing notification access is granted by user, you can check that by here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457733/how-to-get-notification-authorization-status-in-swift-3

the tricky part is, you can only access this value only when app is running on foreground

Answer (score 0):

You can know the Notification settings of the app by using the below code.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in

  print(settings.authorizationStatus.rawValue)

}
```

`settings` has whole lot of information about the notification permission of the app. Please find the Apple document [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsettings)

Comment: Hello @Anand where we call this method.

Comment: You can call it anywhere. I used to call it in didFinishLaunch in AppDelegate

Comment: I getting value 2

Comment: It means permission is allowed. Please find the relevant document: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unauthorizationstatus